# POST Request, restrict to localhost

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am working on a music web app. I am adding a feature where there is a button next to each song to delete it from the database. The page will accomplish this by sending a parameter songId to a PHP page that will deal with it. Now, I want to prevent people being able to send POST requests to that PHP page from a remote server. What conditions can I check to restrict the POST request to originate from my music web app only, or localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '::1') {
    exit('access denied');
}
```

However, this will not protect you against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSRF). To prevent a malicious website from creating a form that POSTs to your application when it's submitted (possibly automatically via JavaScript) you need to implement proper CSRF protection through a secret token an attacker website cannot know.

Comment: It also won't work if you're using a hostname that doesn't map to 127.0.0.1, e.g. the mDNS hostname.

Comment: When accessing it locally chances are good that the loopback interface is used though.

Comment: Thank you. If I told you that the web app page required a login, would they still be able to POST directly to the page?

Comment: CSRF causes *you* to POST to the page, so that doesn't help.